# Switch statement with integer value

Tags: c++, xcode, switch-statement

I am new to C++ and I am stuck on the switch statement because it doesn't seem to give an output when the value in the parentheses is an integer (Console-Program ended with exit code: 0). Although, the same code works fine when I change the type to char.
Thank You.

```
int main()
{
    int num1;          // argument of switch statement must be a char or int or enum
    
    cout<< "enter either 0 or 1" << "\n";
    cin>> num1;
    
    switch (num1)
    {
        case '0':
            cout<< "you entered 0" << endl << endl;
            break;
            
        case '1':
            cout<< "you entered 1" << endl << endl;
            break;
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `'0'` isn't the same as `0`.  One is the character, and the other is a number.

Comment: Additionally,  the character `'0'` is guaranteed to not compare equal to the numeric value of `0`.

Comment: A thought exercise: if you change the definition of `num1` to `char num1` and leave the rest of the code the same, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are switching on an `int`, which is correct, but your cases are not integers - they are `char` since they are surrounded in `'`.

'0' is never equal to 0, nor is '1' ever equal to 1.

**Change the case values to integers.**

```
int main()
{
    int num1;
    
    cout<< "enter either 0 or 1" << "\n";
    cin>> num1;
    
    switch (num1)
    {
        case 0:
            cout<< "you entered 0" << endl << endl;
            break;
            
        case 1:
            cout<< "you entered 1" << endl << endl;
            break;
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int main()
{
    int num1;          // argument of switch statement must be a char or int or enum
    
    cout<< "enter either 0 or 1" << "\n";
    cin>> num1;
    
    switch (num1)
    {
        case 0:
            cout<< "you entered 0" << endl << endl;
            break;
            
        case 1:
            cout<< "you entered 1" << endl << endl;
            break;       
    }

}
```